# Mysq Find the names of aircraft such that all pilots certified to operate them earn more than $80,000

Tags: mysql, relational-division

1. The following relations keep track of airline flight information:

   > FLIGHTS(flno: integer, from: string, to: string, distance: integer, departs:time,arrives: time, price: integer)
   >   AIRCRAFT(aid: integer, aname: string, cruisingrange: integer)
   >   CERTIFIED(eid: integer, aid: integer)
   >   EMPLOYEES(eid: integer, ename: string, salary: integer)

**Note:-** that the Employees relation describes pilots and other kinds of employees as well; every pilot is certified for some aircraft, and only pilots are certified to
fly.

QUESTION:Find the names of aircraft such that all pilots certified to operate them earn more than $80,000.

Help me with this query.my  query IS

```
SELECT  DISTINCT A.aname FROM  AIRCRAFT A WHERE  A.Aid IN 
( SELECT C.aid FROM CERTIFIED C, EMPLOYEES E WHERE C.eid = E.eid AND NOT EXISTS 
( SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES E1 WHERE E1.eid = E.eid AND E1.salary < 80000 )) ;
```

This query gives the name of flight even if any of its employee is earning less than 80,000.

Comment: Why these many subqueries,Try with simple join.

Comment: The answers below are close. The logic is 'return rows for which there are no pilots earning less than 80000'; i.e. `LEFT JOIN... ON... AND salary <= 80000 WHERE... IS NULL `

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct aname FROM aircraft
 JOIN certified ON aircraft.aid = certified.aid
 JOIN employees ON employees.eid = certified.eid
WHERE employees.salary> 80000
 AND aircraft.aid NOT IN 
(SELECT aircraft.aid FROM aircraft
 JOIN certified ON aircraft.aid = certified.aid
 JOIN employees ON employees.eid = certified.eid
WHERE employees.salary <= 80000)
```